# How to add jest specific setup to create-react-native-app?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I created a project with [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) and I want to use `jest-enzyme` matchers, in their Readme there is a [section](https://github.com/blainekasten/enzyme-matchers/tree/master/packages/jest-enzyme#using-with-create-react-app) on how to use it with `create-react-app`, but I did not find any info on how to use it with `create-react-native-app`.

To add these matchers all I need is to create a jest setup file, but `create-react-native-app` does not seen to allow for custom jest setup file.

So it's possible to a use a custom jest setup file without ejecting from create-react-native-app?

Also is there any way to add a `jest` setup file for `create-react-native-app`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/react-native.html which explains as follows:

> Unfortunately, React Native has many environmental dependencies that can be hard to simulate without a host device.
>
> This can be difficult when you want your test suite to run with typical Continuous Integration servers such as Travis.
>
> A pure JS mock of React Native exists and can solve this problem in the majority of use cases.
>
> To install it, run:
>
> **npm i --save-dev react-native-mock**

After adding that dependency you need to import the `/mock` within your tests you should good to go. Maybe I am out of context, you can update your problem and give us some extra context so we can craft a better answer.

Ultimately, there is something important to mention in this thread: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/928 **for the time of this post RN is in version 0.47 and working with react 16 alpha which is not a supported version for enzyme** (the people at enzyme only work with rc versions) so if that is your case things looks quite difficult as there is no official support, however, last comment https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/928#issuecomment-324584942 offers unofficial alternatives

PD: make sure you follow the installation instructions here: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm using react 16 alpha, so it'll check those issues!